# Implementing Enhanced Link Attribution

Tags: google-analytics

On the GA admin page, you have to check the section `Use enhanced link attribution` to activate Google Analytic's Enhanced Link Attribution.

**But how does the code look like?** Even if the feature is new, many sources seem to be dated. Is the code Google publishes [on their doumentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2558867?hl=en&utm_id=ad) page correct and complete, or should it be something else?

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
var pluginUrl = 
 '//www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ga/inpage_linkid.js';
_gaq.push(['_require', 'inpage_linkid', pluginUrl]);
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-Y']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is correct, my full code looks like this

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      var pluginUrl ='//www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ga/inpage_linkid.js';
      _gaq.push(['_require', 'inpage_linkid', pluginUrl]);
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
      _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domainname.com']);
      _gaq.push(['_setAllowAnchor',true]);
      _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',5,'CusVarName','CusVarNameValue',3]);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();
```

But if your setup is basic and according to the example you have given above it should work just fine. As long as you add the pluginUrl variable above the setAccount it should work.